# Trying to truncate csv/txt files leaving header row only

Tags: powershell

I have several csv and txt files in a directory with data in them.  I need to truncate the data from all of these files but leave the header in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following script - it should work, if all files have more than one line...

```
$files = dir .\* -include ('*.csv', '*.txt')

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $firstline = (get-content $file)[0]
    set-content $file -Value $firstline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to read the whole file in order to just capture the first line..

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File | Where-Object { $_.Extension -match '\.(csv|txt)'} | ForEach-Object {
    # only read the first line using -TotalCount
    ($_ | Get-Content -TotalCount 1) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

The above *could* produce empty or whitespace only files if the top line is empty or only contains whitespaces..

Perhaps then the best option to quickly truncate these files to the top NON-EMPTY line would be:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File | Where-Object { $_.Extension -match '\.(csv|txt)'} | ForEach-Object {
    $newcontent = switch -Regex -File $_.FullName {
        '\S'  { $_ ; break}  # output the first line that is not empty or whitespace-only and exit the switch
    }
    # write back to the file
    $newcontent | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

<sup>P.S. Using `-Filter` as parameter on Get-ChildItem would work faster, but unfortunately, the filter can only be used for ONE file pattern only, like '*.csv'.

If you need recursion (search subfolders as well), then you could user the `-Include` parameter which accepts an array of file patterns. However, for that to work, you also need to add switch `-Recurse` OR have the path end in `\*`.

`-Include` is not as fast as `-Filter`, just about the same speed as by using a `Where-Object` clause in the examples above</sup>